# failed to load HTTP source in R

Tags: xml, r, http, parsing, load

I tried to parse the webpage with the code below, but the last line turned out an output of "failed to load HTTP resource". Can anyone tell me how to deal with it? Thanks!
The code is:

```
library(XML);library(RCurl)
page=getForm("http://jobsearch.monster.com/search",query="data science")
doc = htmlParse(page, asText = TRUE)
joblinks = getNodeSet(doc, "//div[@class = 'jobTitleContainer']//a/@href")
htmlParse(joblinks[[1]])
```

Comment: what output are you expecting from it?  It seems to be working as intended

Comment: Really? But on my computer it showed "error:failed to load HTTP resource"

Comment: did you try loading the webpage into your browser?

Comment: Yes I did and successfully loaded the webpage. What is more, I can use htmlParse to load joblinks[[20]].  So I am quite confused.

Answer (score -1):

Two things,  `?htmlParse` will point you to the `isURL` flag, which by default is FALSE.  You want to set this to TRUE.

Secondly, the url in `joblinks[[1]]`  does not seem to work.  This does not appear to be an issue with your `R` code, just the info you are pulling:

```
# works
htmlParse("http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13852853/failed-to-load-http-source-in-r", isURL=TRUE)

# doesnt work 
htmlParse("http://jobview.monster.com/Cleaning-Supervisor-Job-1513-Rebel-Southwest-OH-117109119.aspx", isURL=TRUE)
```